# How to solve this Key Error in Python Data frames?

Tags: python, dataframe, keyerror

I am getting the below error:

```
 **raise KeyError("{} not found in axis".format(labels[mask]))
KeyError: '[18] not found in axis'**
```

I am trying to drop rows based on conditions and my code is below:

```
PSE2=PSE1

for i in range(1,len(PSE1)):
    if PSE1.iloc[[i],[1]].values==PSE1.iloc[[i+1],[1]].values or PSE1.iloc[[i],[1]].values==PSE1.iloc[[i-1],[1]].values:
        pass
    else:
        print(str(i))
        print(PSE2.iloc[[i],[1]].values)
        PSE2=PSE2.drop([i],axis=0)
```

PSE1 and PSE2 are two identical Dataframes.

Comment: Add a [mcve] please.

Comment: When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question, especially if that data is from an external resource.  The easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste from your question (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses. -  [mcve].

Comment: Noted. Though the question is not related to the type of data. It is about boundries

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably comes from the `[i+1]` in the **if** condition. In the last step of your loop, `i = len(PSE1) - 1` so `PSE1.iloc[[i+1],[1]]` will **not** exist

```
for i in range(1,len(PSE1)):
    if PSE1.iloc[[i],[1]].values==PSE1.iloc[[i+1],[1]].values
```

To solve this you can replace your `if`condition by :

```
if PSE1.iloc[[i],[1]].values==PSE1.iloc[[i-1],[1]].values or
i < len(PSE1)-1 and
PSE1.iloc[[i],[1]].values==PSE1.iloc[[i+1],[1]].values:
```